# How to combine data from zip file in .log extension and combine them

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip, logfile

I have downloaded the zip file and extracted the log files from it, however, I am not able to open the .log file format and combine the data in the data frame.

```
import fnmatch
with ZipFile("path/HTWebLog_p1.zip") as zipfiles:

  file_list = zipfiles.namelist()

  #get only the .log files
  csv_files = fnmatch.filter(file_list, "*.log")

  #iterate with a list comprehension to get the individual dataframes
  data = [pd.read_csv(zipfiles.open(file_name), delimiter=',', header=0) for file_name in csv_files]

#combine into one dataframe
df = pd.concat(data)
df.head()
```

Output for csv_files data frame shows the name of files in the zip in .log format.
I am getting the below error.
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 3

Data:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2006-11-01 00:00:08
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2006-11-01 00:00:08 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /Default.aspx - 80 - 70.80.84.76 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1) http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=t&ie=UTF-8&rls=GGLD,GGLD:2005-19,GGLD:en&q=Tulip+hotel 200 0 0
2006-11-01 00:00:08 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /Tulip/home/en-us/home_index.aspx - 80 - 70.80.84.76 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1) - 200 0 0
2006-11-01 00:00:08 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /Tulip/includes/js/CommonUtil.js - 80 - 70.80.84.76 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1) http://www.hotelTulip.com.hk/Tulip/home/en-us/home_index.aspx 200 0 0
```

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

The log files are not CSV files (comma-separated values) so of course the CSV parser chokes on them.

Without knowledge about what exactly you want to extract from the log files, try something like

```py
import fnmatch

data = []
with ZipFile("path/HTWebLog_p1.zip") as zipfiles:
  file_list = zipfiles.namelist()
  log_files = fnmatch.filter(file_list, "*.log")
  for file_name in log_files:
      with zipfiles.open(file_name) as lines:
          data.extend(lines.readlines())
```

This will just read the raw lines into `data`. If you want to parse out individual fields from them, you probably need something a little bit more sophisticated, but at least this should hopefully get you started in the right direction.

In some more detail, the error message tells you that the CSV parser examined the first few lines, and observed that none of them contained a comma, so they each got parsed as a single column of text. But now on line 5 there is suddenly a line which does contain a few commas, which violates the format definition (every record in a CSV file needs to contain the same number of columns).  But of course, if you look at the data, those commas are not actually column delimiters at all.

The data seems to have a fixed number of columns, so perhaps you *could* use the CSV reader if you skipped the first few lines, and used `delimiter=' '` instead (the columns are space-delimited, not comma-delimited).